# center GridView's children horizontally

Tags: android, gridview

I want my rows of gridview be placed in center(horizontally)
I have two columns with same width.
Each item will be placed in center of the respective column.

I tried to follow other answers. None of them worked. 
So frustrating when simple layout doesn't work as intended...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
  <GridView
      android:id="@+id/gridView_album"
      android:numColumns="2"

      android:stretchMode="columnmWidth"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
      android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      >
  </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row's xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_albumTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="album title" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="105dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:src="@drawable/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in your row, root linearlayout => width = match parent + gravity = center

Comment: @njzk2: wow, finally works.. why???

Comment: because this way, the cell takes all the room available, and then the elements are centered in the cell. I recommend using hierachyviewer to see how each element is exactly positioned.

Comment: @njzk2: I once tried googling for hierachyviewer, but it seemed to work with only special devices. am I mistaken?

Comment: you are no entirely mistaken, it works in engineering mode. But it works on the emulator. just run it, it's in the android sdk.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I've done it

Your gridView.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/home_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/holo_blue_color"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now Your gridView Items xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="normal" >

</TextView>
```

Now I made an adapter class which set the image and text

```
class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<String> name;
        ArrayList<Integer> resId;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> name,
                ArrayList<Integer> resId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.resId = resId;

            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return resId.get(arg0);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_textview, null);

            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            tv.setText(name.get(position));
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, resId.get(position),
                    0, 0);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

You do not need to include ImageView. You can align the image around TextView using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

Now just two line in your activity

```
final MyGridAdapter adapter = new MyGridAdapter(this, name, resId);

gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have 5 images per item though. I've simplified my xml.